# wait and thread exact difference

Tags: java, multithreading

I got the the difference between **Thread.sleep() and wait()**.

```
The code sleep(1000); 
puts thread aside for exactly one second. 

The code wait(1000); 
causes a wait of up to one second.
```

What exactly does it mean other than wait is in object class and sleep in Thread class?
Is there any good example available?

Comment: The Javadocs are pretty clear on the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait()` may be awaken by calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()`.
In this example, you can see as Blah1 doesn't wait 1000 miliseconds because it's awaken by Blah2 earlier. Blah2 waits.

`wait()` method releases monitor which is blocked by given thread. `sleep()` doesn't.

`sleep()` can be interrupted by calling `interrupt()` method.

```
public class Blah implements Runnable {

    private String name;

    public Blah(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (Blah.class) {
                System.out.println(name + ": Before notify " + new Date().toString());
                Blah.class.notifyAll();
                System.out.println(name + ": Before wait " + new Date().toString());
                Blah.class.wait(1000);
                System.out.println(name + ": After " + new Date().toString());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Blah("Blah1"));
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Blah("Blah2"));
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Blah1: Before notify Tue Jan 13 09:19:09 CET 2015
Blah1: Before wait Tue Jan 13 09:19:09 CET 2015
Blah2: Before notify Tue Jan 13 09:19:09 CET 2015
Blah2: Before wait Tue Jan 13 09:19:09 CET 2015
Blah1: After Tue Jan 13 09:19:09 CET 2015
Blah2: After Tue Jan 13 09:19:10 CET 2015
```

Comment: `Sleep()` can be *interruped as well*.

Answer (score 6):

You call `wait()` on an object you've synchronized on, and it releases the monitor and waits for a `notify()` or `notifyAll()` to be called on that same object. It's usually used to coordinate activity on some shared object, such as a request or connection queue.

`sleep()` doesn't release any monitors or otherwise interact directly with other threads. Instead, it retains all monitors and simply stops executing the current thread for a little bit.

Comment: Releasing monitor is what I had on my mind in my first answer :) Thanks. Need some coffee, I guess.